# what would the graph of this complex function would look like and the values for x if ζ(x,1)=1 i have attched the equation image below

Tags: analysis, multivalued-functions

[zeta equation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m4fd.png)
I made an attempt to calculate the value of the entire function, as indicated in the attached image. Specifically, I sought to determine the value of x at which  ***[ζ(x,1)=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgiOn.png)*** However, I encountered challenges in the process. Additionally, I am intrigued by the potential graphical representation of this function. If this image link does not work this link will work https://drive.google.com/file/d/14h2iC_fNC9wg-H-wbvA0nknjIcK1bNmH/view?usp=sharing